# Secure HTML5 offline web application - Detect when app cache has been modified

Tags: html, security, cryptography, http-headers, application-cache

Let's say I'm building a "secure" offline HTML5 app which must be run locally in the web browser without needing to download more files from the server. Let's say I connect to the server initially with the web browser over HTTPS (TLS) and download the HTML, JavaScript and CSS required to run locally. I can reasonably assume that the first time I download the files that it is done securely as it is a brand new server that no-one else knows about yet. All the files get stored in the [HTML5 Offline Application Cache](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#offline). Now I have everything I need to run the application locally and shouldn't depend on the server for anything else.

Now every time I run the app, the application will use the HTML5 Offline Web Application Manifest to see if there are any updates from the server for the app to be downloaded. Potentially this could be a problem. If an attacker has now targeted my server and has done a MITM attack on the connection they could alter the application manifest, causing an update to be triggered and therefore make the client download new JavaScript and HTML. This would easily compromise the security of the application as the application relies on the integrity of those files.

What are some possible options to prevent this? Can we do any of these:

**1)** Completely disable or block updates from the server after all files have been downloaded. Then if the manifest is changed on the server, or the attacker serves up a new manifest, then the client ignores the new manifest and keeps using it's local copy of the files.

**2)** Detect if the manifest has been changed, or an update event triggered, or the browser is downloading new files. Therefore notify the user that this has occurred. And if it's not expected from the user, then it would indicate an attack. I understand that the there is a 'downloading' or 'updateready' or 'checking' event listed in the spec. Is there a way for the JavaScript to detect that those events have been fired?

**3)** Store a version value or cryptographic hash of the files inside the browser's local storage. Then on page startup, if the files change unexpectedly, we can throw up an alert to the web browser notifying the user they have been unexpectedly changed.

**4)** Perhaps use [some sort of cache header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980792/html5-application-cache-cached-files-do-not-update-even-when-manifest-is-upda?rq=1) that forces the browser to cache the files indefinitely. In other words, a kind of hack to make it ignore new manifest files that are sent by the server. This sounds like it could probably work as there are lots of issues that can cause the application not to update even when the manifest file is changed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you trust TLS for a single download, but don't trust it going forward? This seems a bit of an unusual attitude...

Comment: @bobince Well trust it in the sense that the user will be downloading the code from the new server once. We can reasonably assume that no-one else will know about the server or have time to attack it before the user can download the code the first time. After an extended period of time, I have reason to believe the server could be a target of attack. If it was MITM'd there's no guarantee of the integrity of the client. The attacker could simply send modified JavaScript down the wire. That's why I want the code downloaded once, and then impossible for the server to overwrite it.